# Limiting output with different criterias

Tags: sql, filter, db2, row-number

I have the following SQL statement:

```
select 
row_number() over(),
car, group, yearout 
from (select..... )inner 
where year(inner.yearout) between '2010' and '2030'
order by inner.group)temp
```

the output is like

```
1  test1   1   2010
2  test2   1   2010
3  test3   1   2012
4  test1   2   2010
5  test1   3   2011
```

and so on.

There is another table called outerno with is filled like:

```
no   yearo    amnt
1    2010     10
2    2010     15
3    2010     5
4    2010     10
5    2010     15
6    2010     8
1    2011     4
2    2011     15
```

and so on.

There are 6 groups in the table for each year.

Now the problem is that I need to limit the output of the query as stated in the outerno table. 
So I need the first 10 row for 2010 for group 1, the first 15 rows of 2010 for group 2 and so on. For each year and group there is a value in the outerno.

I tried to use row_number but I don't know how to limit the output in this way since I would be needing for example rows 1-10, 50-65, 83-88 and so on.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

TheVagabond

Comment: There is a parenthesis too many in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use ROW_NUMBER() to give you record numbers per group. Then add a WHERE clause to only get row numbers up to the desired number. In ROW_NUMBER's ORDER BY you can spcify which records to prefer.

```
select row_number() over (), car, group, yearout
from
(
  select 
    row_number() over (partition by inner.group, inner.yearout order by inner.car) as rn,
    inner.car, inner.group, inner.yearout 
  from (select..... ) inner 
  where inner.yearout between '2010' and '2030'
  order by inner.group
) all_records
where all_records.rn <=
(
  select amnt
  from outerno 
  where outerno.year = all_records.yearout
  and outerno.no = all_records.group
);
```

BTW: I wouldn't choose `group` for a column name, as it is a reserved word in SQL.

Comment: With this I only get the first line (first car) of that year eventhough it should be the first 10. The rn counter goes over all the years so only the first year can be below 10. The counter should start at 0 every year on every group.

Comment: You are right, the partition within which row numbers are created must of course consist of group *and yearout*. I've corrected my answer.